# Increment by one everytime loop runs

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

How can I make the cell number increase by one every time it loops through all of the sheets? I got it to loop through the different sheets itself but I'm not sure how to add +1 to the cell value.

```
for sheet in sheetlist:
        wsX = wb.get_sheet_by_name('{}'.format(sheet))

        ws2['D4'] = wsX['P6'].value
```

I'm trying to get just the `['D4']` to change to D5,D6,D7.. etc up to 25 automatically.

Comment: Can you add a fully reproducible example?

Comment: You need a second loop.

Comment: You should include all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

No need for counters or clumsy string conversion: openpyxl provides an API for programmatic access.

```
for idx, sheet in enumerate(sheetlist, start=4):
   wsX = wb[sheet]
   cell = ws2.cell(row=idx, column=16)
   cell.value = wsX['P6']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, sheet in enumerate(sheetlist):
    wsX = wb.get_sheet_by_name('{}'.format(sheet))

    cell_no = 'D' + str(i + 4)
    ws2[cell_no] = wsX['P6'].value
```

Answer (score 0):

write this outside of the loop :

```
x = 'D4'
```

write this in the loop :

```
x = x[0] + str(int(x[1:])+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one... it's commented so you can understand what it's doing.

```
#counter
i = 4

for sheet in sheetlist:
    #looping from D4 to D25
    while i <= 25:
        wsX = wb.get_sheet_by_name('{}'.format(sheet))

        #dynamic way to get the cell
        cell1 = 'D' + str(i)

        ws2[cell1] = wsX['P6'].value

        #incrementing counter
        i += 1
```